# How to convert Dynamics 365 Virtual Agent topics and trigger phrases into intents and utterances to LU file format

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, dynamics-365, azure-bot-service

I trying to integrate a power virtual agent bot with some flows to a bot that i have already created and deployed to teams.
So im following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-use-dispatcher
As its said im trying to create a dispatcher and for that first i need to run the ContentConverter utility sample and im using:  dotnet run -p ContentConverter.csproj -c Release -- -i  -c  -b

But im getting the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect."[image]

Comment: Could the problem be that you've put angle brackets around your paths?

Comment: Oh yes..how silly can i be to ignore that !!!!! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths should not include angle brackets (`<>`). Angle brackets are used in sample commands to show something that needs to be replaced by your own info.